# Why is this html table not aligned right?

Tags: html, css, layout

Always when i send an email with this pattern (there is more code, but the problem is at the table), the table is not correct showed up. The rows are horizontal not vertical.

[View from mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmE2Y.png)

If needed i can post css and whole html code. I am new at stackoverflow, so sorry if this post does not fit with the regular template.

```
<table>
      <tr>
           <th>Beruf</th>
           <th>Unternehmen</th>
           <th>Ort</th>
           <th>Freie Plätze</th>
           <th>Ausbildungsnummer</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[0][1][0]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[3][1][0]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[1][1][0]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[4][1][0]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center"><a href="https://www.ihk-lehrstellenboerse.de/suche?query=""" + str(jobs[5][1][0]) + """>Zur Stelle</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[0][1][1]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[3][1][1]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[1][1][1]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[4][1][1]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center"><a href="https://www.ihk-lehrstellenboerse.de/suche?query=""" + str(jobs[5][1][1]) + """>Zur Stelle</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[0][1][2]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[3][1][2]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[1][1][2]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[4][1][2]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center"><a href="https://www.ihk-lehrstellenboerse.de/suche?query=""" + str(jobs[5][1][2]) + """>Zur Stelle</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[0][1][3]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[3][1][3]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[1][1][3]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[4][1][3]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center"><a href="https://www.ihk-lehrstellenboerse.de/suche?query=""" + str(jobs[5][1][3]) + """>Zur Stelle</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[0][1][4]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[3][1][4]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[1][1][4]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center">""" + str(jobs[4][1][4]) + """</td>
           <td class="align-center"><a href="https://www.ihk-lehrstellenboerse.de/suche?query=""" + str(jobs[5][1][4]) + """>Zur Stelle</a></td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML?

Comment: It's acting like it doesn't see the `</tr>` tags.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FrD15ZWh

Comment: Got that html code from the firefox element inspector

Comment: Add this class class="align-center" to you <th> cells. That should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing " in your hrefs

Comment: Thank you! Worked